# Matlab App designer how to resize UIAxes to the same size an image and manually set the y&x axis values

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Originally what I was trying to do was plot a spectogram natively in app designer, however I was informed that this is not possible. Please let me know if this is though!
I have a workaround at the moment where I store the spectogram as an image. I've run into a few problems into setting the uiAxes to be the same size as the image and then setting the axis of the data to the freq(x) and time(y) respectively. This is what I have so far
[image] and this is what I want to achieve.[image] I have tried finding the size of the image using [h,w,d]= size(Image) however this just returns 1,1,1. I also have no idea how to set the axis to time and freq respectively and have it line up with the image.
This is my code to generate the spectogram

```
ax = uiaxes(app.UIFigure,"Position",app.UIAxes.Position);
[S,F,T] = spectrogram(y,256,200,256,app.fs);
z=imagesc(ax, T, F, log(abs(S'))); %plot the log spectrum`
[height,width,depth]=size(z)
ax.Position=[113,99,width,height];
 set(ax,'YDir', 'normal');
 plot(F,T);
colorbar(ax)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer, but yes you can plot a spectrogram in app designer.

below is a snippet of the code I used.

```
[s,f,t] = spectrogram(app.Bx.Data,512,50,512,app.Frequency);
imagesc(app.UIAxesPSBx,t,f,log(abs(s)));
app.UIAxesPSBx.View = [90 90];
app.UIAxesPSBx.YLim = [0 (app.Frequency/2)];
app.UIAxesPSBx.YLabel.String = 'Frequency (Hz)';
app.UIAxesPSBx.XLim = [0 (app.DataLength/app.Frequency)];
app.UIAxesPSBx.XLabel.String = 'Time (UTC)';
colorbar(app.UIAxesPSBx, 'Color',[0.8 0.8 0.8]);
```

just remember that your changing the view angle for the UI axes, so if you want to change it to a Welch power spectral density you'll need to change the view angle as below.

```
[pxx,f] = pwelch(app.Bx.Data,[],[],[],app.Frequency);
line(app.UIAxesPSBx,f,10*log10(pxx),'Color',[0.27 0.87 1], 'LineWidth',0.8);
app.UIAxesPSBx.View = [0 90];
app.UIAxesPSBx.YLimMode = 'auto';
app.UIAxesPSBx.XLimMode = 'auto';
colorbar(app.UIAxesPSBx,'off');
app.UIAxesPSBx.XLabel.String = 'Frequency (Hz)';
app.UIAxesPSBx.YLabel.String = 'Power/frequency (dB/Hz)';
```